# Help calculating Avg and std for excel files saved as CSV

Tags: python, csv, python-3.x, statistics

I have about 20 excel files saved as CSV in a single folder. Each excel file has numbers saved in the first, second and third columns. I was trying to read the first column for all of the files, second column for all of the file, and third column for all of the files using CSV module in python, and calulate the average and standard deviation for each column and save these results in a single separate excel. please help.... this is what i have so far...how can i access each column separately?

```
import csv
import os
from numpy import array

path="A:\\hello\\folder"
dirList=os.listdir(path)
for file in dirList:
    fullpath=os.path.join(path,file)
##    print fullpath
    with open(fullpath, 'rb') as f:
        [[val for val in line.split(',')] for line in f.readlines()]
##        print line
        nums = array([line])

        for row in nums:
            print row.mean()
```

Comment: So... What's your real probem?

Comment: i have done this before using xlrd and numpy, but that was when the excel files are saved as 'xls'. im not very famillier with csv files. i have done some research on python.org...but i still dont understand most of the stuff

Comment: and for each files the columns are labeled as x, y, and z. the first column is x, the second y and the third z. i want to calculate the average of the column x for all of the files, column y for all of the files, and column z for all of the files, and save the result in a separate excel

Comment: Please see the revised solution below. Works for you?

Comment: Are you open to solutions in other languages? :)

Answer (score 2):

A [**list comprehension**](http://docs.python.org/tutorial/datastructures.html#list-comprehensions) works kinda like a backwards for-loop that automatically constructs a `list` for you. If you nest these with the "columns" on the inside and the "rows" on the outside you should get a matrix thingy (nested list structure):

```
nums = [[int(val) for val in line.split(',')] for line in my_file.readlines()]
```

Or maybe if you have a csv reader object it might be like this:

```
nums = [[int(val) for val in line] for line in my_csv_reader]
```

And now you've got your matrix in a variable called `nums` thanks to the above *list comprehension*.

Then you should probably use [numpy](http://new.scipy.org/download.html) to compute your stats. This is nice because you can access columns of a numpy array very easily and when you do it returns the column in the form of a numpy array. numpy arrays also happen to have built-in methods for mean and standard deviation. You can cast your `nums` to a numpy array just by passing it into the `array()` constructor function :

```
from numpy import array
anums = array(nums)
```

Then if you want to iterate through columns, use the array slice notation and the `shape` variable that is a member of every numpy array:

```
# The 1 index of anums.shape should tell you how many columns you have
for c in range(anums.shape[1]):
    column = anums[:,c]
    col_mean = column.mean()
    col_std = column.std()
    # Do something with these variables here, probably
```

Comment: how can i print each column separately?

Comment: i get what you are saying, but that is not what im trying to do. i want to calculate the average and std for each columns as it is. i don't want to change the rows in to columns. i have a lot of numbers saved in each excel file for each column.

Comment: so i have a lot of number...like more than 10,000 rows in the each excel.and i have about 20 excels in the folder. so when i try to run it would say try to reduce the number to flexible amount....

Comment: I don't get it... 30,000 values should not cause a problem with memory at all. What's troubling you? The numpy functions?